# How do I hook before the user is created in Behat tests?

Tags: testing

I have a Behat test where I have a *Given user* step, and I want to alter some fields (token replacements). Which Behat hook should I use? I know that for *Given content*, the Behat hook would be @beforeNodeCreate.

Which hook is for users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat predictably, which I'm pretty sure is deliberate, it's `@beforeUserCreate`.

The [Drupal Extension Hooks](https://behat-drupal-extension.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/contexts.html#drupal-extension-hooks) section of the docs has a bit of background in case you need it.